# Can you save json data without being archived

Tags: json, swift

I want to save json data into a file without being archived. This way I can open the file and check if everything is okay

```
// valid json data
if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonData) {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as! String
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.json")
    println(path) // if I open the file from finder, all the data is archived


    // try 1: the jsonData is archived
    if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(jsonData, toFile: path) {
        println("saved: true");
    }

    let stringTest = "asd"
    stringTest.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSStringEncoding.allZeros, error: nil)
    // the string is also archived

}
```

I also try

```
var jsonNSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(jsonData)
var string = NSString(data: jsonNSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(string) // returns nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by casting your JSON to NSDictionary and then just write it to user documents directory:

```
var someJsonAsDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["foo": "string", "bar": NSNumber(integer: 5)]

if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as? [String],
    let documentsDirectory = paths.first
{
    let filePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myPlistFile")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    //IMPORTANT - someJsonAsDict cannot have primite types(they must be boxed in Appropriate NSNumber, NSValue, etc)
    (someJsonAsDict as NSDictionary).writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

    //print path of simulator so you can read it from terminal
    println("target path is \(filePath)")
}
```

If you happen to have Array as most outer object of JSON, just replace:

```
someJsonAsDict as NSDictionary
```

with appropriate array method:

```
someJsonAsDict as NSArray
```

All this will create plist file with the JSON. If you happen to need it in raw json style(as like txt) you can use plutil(installed with Xcode command line tools):

```
plutil -convert json myPlistFile.plist -o MyTxtFile.json
```

Comment: error: Cast from '[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Comment: I've updated my answer, however your object is clearly an Array holding a Dictionary. Please revive whether you need to save array or dictionary(it's pretty much the same althout you need to call as NSArray instead of NSDictionary).

Comment: (jsonData as NSArray).writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true) // this save the data but in plist format.. I want to save it into json format

Comment: Just use plutil command line tool: plutil -convert json myPlistFile.plist -o myPlistFile.json. Note you gonna need Xcode developer tools for this ;)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use NSUserDefaults to archive value. like `var save = NSUserdefaults.userdefaults()`then `var ValueSaved = save.setObject(stringTest, "StringTest")` this is the easiest mode to archive a file.. but it doesn't archive in a file :\